What's the proper way to use sed to replace a whole line in a CSV file without messing it up?
case $selectedField in
    fullname)
        sed -i '' "/$argname/ s/\([^,]*,\)[^,]*/\1$argnewdata/" "$filename"
        ;;
    age)
        sed -i '' "/$argname/ s/\([^,]*,[^,]*,\)[^,]*/\1$argnewdata/" "$filename"
        ;;
    country)
        sed -i '' "/$argname/ s/\([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,\)[^,]*/\1$argnewdata/" "$filename"
        ;;
    status)
        sed -i '' "/$argname/ s/\([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,\)[^,]*/\1$argnewdata/" "$filename"
        ;;
    rescued)
        sed -i '' "/$argname/ s/\([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,\)[^,]*/\1$argnewdata/" "$filename"
        ;;
    record)
        if [[ $argnewdata =~  ^[0-9]+,.*,[0-9]+,.*,(Passenger|Crew),(Yes|No)$ ]]; then
            sed -i '' "/$argname/c\\
            $argnewdata" "$filename"
            #echo $argnewdata
        else
            echo "Invalid format. Please try again."
        fi
        #sed -i '' "/$argname/c$new_value" "$filename"
        #$argnewdata =~ ^[0-9]+,.*,[0-9]+,.*,(Passenger|Crew),(Yes|No)$
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Invalid field."
        return
        ;;
esac

this is my code, sorry its messed up.
on the case statement on case record) when i use this to replace a csv file this happens:
1312,Nikol,37,asdffe,Passenger,Yes32,Nikolas,98,jsiajsi,Passenger,Yes

whats wrong is that it collides the line bellow and adds many whitespaces in the beginning(i dont know if the whitespaces are shown).
i found that if i delete the white spaces used for the right format before the second line of the sec c\ command it fixes that. that means that instead of only replacing the old text with the variable it also adds the spaces before it. How can i avoid it so i dont have to mess the format. Also why does it collide the line bellow?
expected:
1312,Nikolaos,37,asdffe,Passenger,Yes
32,Nikolas,98,jsiajsi,Passenger,Yes

actual:
1312,Nikolaos,37,asdffe,Passenger,Yes32,Nikolas,98,jsiajsi,Passenger,Yes


For column handling, the standard tool to use is generally awk, not sed

In your example, are $selectedField == "fullname" and $argnewdata == "Nikolaos"? You know, you branch different sed commands so how are we supposed to know which one it is?

There is no "proper way to use sed to replace a whole line in a CSV file without messing it up". Anything you try with sed will have corner cases that it doesn't work for. You might want to take a look at whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk and/or look into other tools that have built in CSV parsing.

TL;DR: Use s\ instead of c\ (for field); include remaining columns in replacement strings and anchor with ^ and $ (for other $argname); escape /, &, and \ in $newargdata; handle "Kerri, John" with ([^,]*|"[^"]*"); and consider awk or Polars/Pandas instead.
Fix the case option
c\ deletes an entire line, including the newline, so just  add \n: sed -i '' "/$argname/c\\$argnewdata\n" "$filename". But s\ is more direct:
sed -i '' "/$argname/ s/.*/$argnewdata/" "$filename"

Fix the other options
To use the fullname option, you would need to pass (at command-line) the new fullname PLUS the columns after it. You're using:

s/\([^,]*,[^,]*,\)[^,]*/\1$argnewdata/"


Instead, you can use the following search pattern for every $selectedField. By the way, note the ^. Without it, you'll get matches at the wrong columns. The $ just guards in case a row incorrectly has extra (>5) columns.
Note: For readability, I'll leave regex plain, not  escaped for sed.
^([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)$

Then just change the replacement string differently per case. E.g., for country, use (where $newdata is defined below): \1\2$newdata\3\4\5.
Escape the replacement text
Using $argnewdata directly is a problem if it could contain /, &, or \. Refer to SO:2705678/4024340. You can do this with Bash parameter substitution:
newdata=$argnewdata
newdata="${newdata//\//\\/}"  # escape /
newdata="${newdata//&/\\&}"   # escape &
newdata="${newdata//\\/\\\\}" # escape \

Handle quoted strings containing ,
CSV usually uses "" to surround fields containing ,; e.g. "Kerri, John". Any double quotes inside a quoted field are doubled; e.g. "Kerri, John ""The Beast""". You can match a field properly with [^,]*|"([^"]|"")*". Your full pattern becomes:
^([^,]+|"([^"]|"")+"), ... ([^,]+|"([^"]|"")+")$

Sanitize input to ensure passing Kerri, John doesn't break your CSV file:
if [[ "$newdata" == *','* && ! "$newdata" =~ ^\"[^\"]*\"$ ]]
    then newdata="\"${newdata//\"/\"\"}\""
fi

Consider using -E
sed -E switches the default Basic Regular Expressions (BRE) to Extended Regular Expressions (ERE). ERE also allows +, ?, and |. It also inverts (really, corrects) the escaping regex metacharacters like (, *, and .:



mode
.
\.
+
?
|




BRE
literal
meta
✗
✗
✗


ERE
meta
literal
✓
✓
✓



Corrected: -E is POSIX-standard. See POSIX bug 528.
Avoid using -i ''
-i '' is not usually recommended because it can corrupt your input file. Plus, that syntax only works on BSD and macOS.
Use nonzero return and exit codes:

echo "Invalid format. Please try again."
exit 1   # <-------------- here
# [...]
*)
    echo "Invalid field."
    return 1   # <-------- here
    ;;


Consider a more robust tool
E.g. awk, as @Fravadona commented. Or, Python and Polars or Pandas, which automatically handle CSV robustly.
Let me know if I made a mistake (I'll correct it).

@DavidC.Rankin Thanks, fixed.
